# SQL Server Network Interfaces: Error Locating Server/Instance Specified [xFFFFFFFF]. - One assembly only

Tags: .net, sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2014, asp.net-4.5

I am getting the above error only in one project, using a DataReader.  This reader connects to a SQL Server 2014 instance, with default instance (MSSQLSERVER).

There are other parts of the same project that connect to the same server successfully using LINQ to SQL, using the same connection string (only written once in the web config, no where else).  However when the DataReader is executed I get the above error.

If I change the connection string to be deliberately wrong, I get a different error, so it must be connecting to some degree.

The data reader is executing a stored procedure.  Now oddly this project and code worked fine on a previous SQL Server 2008 R2 with a named instance.  Equally strange, the same code works with the new server in a different Visual studio project.

Any ideas on what setting could possibly be causing this?  I have tried it locally and on a different server and the issue appears both places.

Code below:

```
    Dim conn As SqlConnection
    Try

        conn = New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnString").ConnectionString)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw New Exception(String.Format("Connection string {0} not found in web config file", "ConnString"), ex)
    End Try

    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(_methodSettings.MethodName)
    cmd.Connection = connection
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure

    cmd.CommandTimeout = 300000 
    conn.Open()

    'Error occurs here:
    Dim dr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
```

Connection string in web config:

```
 <add name="ConnString" connectionString="Data Source=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;Initial Catalog=Database;User Id=xxxx;Password=xxxx" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Same code, same connection string, same SQL is working but in a different VS Project...

Comment: Post the code and the connection string (with the private bits * out obvs)

Comment: Do you have more than one instance of SQL Server on that machine?

Comment: Nope, just the one default instance

Comment: Try configuring firewall and SQL Browser Services like [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/8cdc71eb-6929-4ae8-a5a8-c1f461bd61b4/provider-sql-network-interfaces-error-26-error-locating-serverinstance-specified?forum=sqlexpress) or specify port directly in connection string like `Data Source=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:1433`

Comment: Tried that already (Data Source=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx,1433 for .NET) - same error.  Windows firewall off, all traffic allowed.

Comment: Are you sure this is correct port, not for example 1435?

Comment: Any other port gives "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server."

Comment: Found the issue here, which was stupidly overlooked.  The stored procedure was calling across a linked server (hadn't noticed this).  The linked server hadn't been setup correctly, and this error was propagating up from the linked server call.